# Intel c++ CreateWindow kernel resource leak

Tags: c++, memory, resources, memory-leaks, intel

I am using Parallel Studio (from Intel) and the Intel c++ Compiler.

The Memory Problem analyzer always tells me, that I have a Kernel resource leak in my `CreateWindow` function.

The Function Call is located at line 26 in my Header File.

No matter what I do, the leak always appears (calling `DestroyWindow` in the Destructor of the class etc.)

Header:
http://beta.pastie.org/private/ze8x59f1nfkjz0wcrromew

Source: 
http://beta.pastie.org/5425046

Answer (score 0):

The class in the code you linked doesn't have a destructor.

Anyway, it might be something that CreateWindow does that looks like a memory leak but isn't.

P.S. don't register the WNDCLASS on each instantiation of a CWindow. Register it once at program startup. You can create a private WindowClass singleton class inside CWindow that handles window class registration:

```
class CWindow
{
private:
    class CWindowClass
    {
    private:
        static CWindowClass m_windowClass;

        CWindowClass()
        {
            // Register a WNDCLASS
        }

        ~CWindowClass() {}
    }

    ...
};
```